# Navigation Bar in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a treeview in my asp.net page. I want to make my navigation as shown in the above attached picture..[image]

when i tried it, i am getting an error which says :

> `HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ABID-PC\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=SamleNavigation;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select cat_Name from _NavParent", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        TreeViewSample.DataSource = dt;
        TreeViewSample.DataBind();


    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Abid.

Comment: It means that data which you bind to the `TreeView` control should be hierarchical, should contains parent and child nodes. For example it may be `XmlDataSource`.

Comment: In many cases one can say that _"A picture is worth a thousand words"_. But in this case however, you're _much_ better of showing us the relevant pieces of your code instead...

Answer (score 0):

The following is a posible solution. 
What it asks is the datatype which is convenient for the treeview.

First of all you must create your `Category` class

```
// Your primary class
public class Category {
    public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Int32? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }

    // List of children if any.
    // In this example if your category doesn't have any children
    // it is supposed to be null
    public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
    // The parent category. If this is your topmost category 
    // this property is deemed to be null.
    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public override String ToString() {
        return this.CategoryName;
    }
}
```

It has a reference to the parent and a list of children. If the category the topmost, `Parent` property is `null`. If it has no children it also can be null.

Then you'll need the specified wrappers. 
Here are they

```
// your primary tree
public class CategoryTree : IHierarchicalEnumerable {
    // Field to keep the collection data
    private IEnumerable<Category> Categories;
    // Empty constructor
    public CategoryTree() {
        //Init an empty list to avoid NullReferenceException
        Categories = new List<Category>();
    }
    // Primary constructor of our interest
    public CategoryTree(IEnumerable<Category> categories) {
        // Assign the collection data to the internal list
        Categories = categories;
    }
    public IHierarchyData GetHierarchyData(object enumeratedItem) {
        //cast the object
        var cat = enumeratedItem as Category;
        //create a new hierarchy item
        return new CategoryHierarchyItem(cat);
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        //IEnumerable support for foreach loop
        return Categories.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

and

```
// Container that the TreeView control needs
public class CategoryHierarchyItem : IHierarchyData {
    // Internal field to store your data
    private Category _Item;

    // the constructor used to instantiate the class
    public CategoryHierarchyItem(Category input) {
        this._Item = input;
    }

    // returns another tree with children if any
    public IHierarchicalEnumerable GetChildren() {
        if (_Item.Children != null)
            return new CategoryTree(_Item.Children);
        return new CategoryTree();
    }

    // The boolean value indicating weather this is the deepest level of your
    // categories
    public Boolean HasChildren {
        get { return _Item.Children != null; }
    }

    // Actual data item
    public Object Item {
        get { return _Item; }
    }

    // This is the path. 
    // Construct it as you think is necessary.
    // Here the format is the same as in namespaces of C#
    public String Path {
        get {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var current = _Item;
            sb.Append(_Item.CategoryName);
            while (current != null) {
                sb.Insert(0, ".");
                sb.Insert(0, current.CategoryName);
                current = current.Parent;
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public String Type {
        get { return "Category"; }
    }

    // returns the parent of the current item
    public IHierarchyData GetParent() {
        if (_Item.Parent != null)
            return new CategoryHierarchyItem(_Item.Parent);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've used the above codes with the dummy data. It looks approximately like this.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // The topmost category
        var top = new Category() {
            CategoryId = 1,
            CategoryName = "Top category"
        };
        // Prepare children for them
        var children = new List<Category>();
        // assign the children
        top.Children = children;
        // Populate the child list
        children.Add(new Category {
            CategoryId = 2,
            CategoryName = "First child",
            Parent = top
        });
        children.Add(new Category {
            CategoryId = 3,
            CategoryName = "Second child",
            Parent = top
        });
        //Add another sub child
        var thirdLevel = new List<Category>();
        thirdLevel.Add(new Category { 
            CategoryId = 4,
            CategoryName = "Sub sub category",
            Parent = children[0]
        });
        // assign it to the first child
        children[0].Children = thirdLevel;
        // Make up a new tree
        var tree = new CategoryTree(new[] { top });
        //Bind the source.
        TreeView1.DataSource = tree;
        // Bind it and enjoy.
        TreeView1.DataBind();
    }
```

You can modify the solution as much as you can.
Most likely you have to divide your logic into data access and UI tree building.

Comment: what if there may b categories of sub- categories then?
i dont think this is a possible solution if i hardcode here the names of categories.. 
what say?

Comment: i want nth categories solution which can be modified by the user when ever he wants to..

Comment: @AbidAli Don't pay attention. To my "Hard code demo". This is just an example. Your real life code should populate the topmost category list and recursively children. The depth can be as much as you wish. It is literally 'eternal'.